# WinUI3 : ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D->SetDevice() -> exception and GPU memory leak

Tags: directx, winui-3

Folowing this SurfaceImageSource example adapted for WinUI3 :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop

At the line :

```
sisNativeWithD2D->SetDevice(d2dDevice.get());
```

I got an exception, but the code of the example is working for a while and then laggy because of a GPU Memory increase !

> \Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll!00007FFBA37099D5: (caller: 00007FFBA373D3AD) ReturnHr(4) tid(4df8) 80004002 No such interface supported

Here's the minimal code to reproduce the issue (from a WinUI3 C++ empty project, called within a Timer) :

```
void MainWindow::UpdateImageMinimal()
{
    // Compute performance counters
    LARGE_INTEGER previous = mpc_Start;
    m_counter++;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&mpc_Start);
    float refreshRate = 0;
    if ((mpc_Start.QuadPart - previous.QuadPart) > 0)
        refreshRate = (float)mpc_Freq.QuadPart / (mpc_Start.QuadPart - previous.QuadPart);

    // Initialize DirectX (inspired from this example :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop)
    winrt::com_ptr<::ID3D11Device> d3dDevice;
    uint32_t creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL supportedFeatureLevel;
    winrt::check_hresult(::D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        0,
        creationFlags,
        featureLevels,
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        d3dDevice.put(),
        &supportedFeatureLevel,
        nullptr)
    );

    // Get the DXGI device.
    winrt::com_ptr<::IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice{
        d3dDevice.as<::IDXGIDevice>() };

    // Create the Direct2D device and a corresponding context.
    winrt::com_ptr<::ID2D1Device> d2dDevice;
    ::D2D1CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.get(), nullptr, d2dDevice.put());

    winrt::com_ptr<::ID2D1DeviceContext> d2dDeviceContext;
    winrt::check_hresult(
        d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
            D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
            d2dDeviceContext.put()
        )
    );

    SurfaceImageSource surfaceImageSource(500, 500);

    winrt::com_ptr<::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> sisNativeWithD2D{
        surfaceImageSource.as<::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D>() };

    // Associate the Direct2D device with the SurfaceImageSource.
    // THIS LINE IS CAUSING GPU MEMORY LEAK and EXCEPTION
    sisNativeWithD2D->SetDevice(d2dDevice.get());

    // Show performances counters : rate & count
    std::wstring str = L"Rate " + std::to_wstring(refreshRate)  + L" , count = " + std::to_wstring(m_counter) + L"\n";
    textStatus().Text(str);
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with the code example and the right way to use ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D with WinUI3 application ?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code, all details are important. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example